# views.setTextViewTextSize causing app crash?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am making a homescreen widget along with settings page. user can choose the widget font size from the settings page. I was able to successfully send the font size value to the updateAppWidget method and it is successfully captured in the string variable "fontSize".

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) 
{
        CharSequence widgetSettings = myWidgetConfigureActivity.loadSettings(context, appWidgetId, PREF_PREFIX_KEY_SETTINGS);

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);

        //read settings
        String fontSize = "";

        String[] splitTextSettings = widgetSettings.toString().split("%");
        if (splitTextSettings.length > 1) {
            fontSize = splitTextSettings[1].trim();            
        }

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.txtHeaderText, fontSize);


       // ###################  this works. ####################
       views.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.txtQuoteText, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, Float.parseFloat("20"));

       // ###################  this does not work ###############
       views.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.txtQuoteText, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, Float.parseFloat(fontSize));

        // More code here
        ....
        ....
        ....

        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
```

The problem is when I pass this fontSize variable in setTextViewTextSize method, it does not work and I see "widget has stopped working". However if I hard code the value in the same method, it works, but since the value is hard coded, it always show the same text size.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you print `fontSize` and see the value given to `Float.parsefloat();` ?

Comment: please show us the logcat output...

Comment: Hi Android developer, I am showing font size in R.id.txtHeaderText textView. it's correctly coming as "25", or "27" etc. but while applying the same as size it is not working.

Comment: Hi Opiatefuchs, the log shows something about ArrayOutOf Bound exception.

Comment: please copy and paste it here...thanks

Comment: if You have ArrayOutOfBound, I suspect that Your fontSize = splitTextSettings[1].trim(); is the issue. Maybe there is no second value inside splitTextSettings..